# anchor tags and scrollTo do nothing on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a navigation bar that works like this:

```
<a onclick="$('body').scrollTo('#step2');" class="navLink">
```

OR

```
<a href="#step2" class="navLink">
```

To link to other sections of the same page, like so:

```
<a id="step2"></a>
```

I have tried both versions of the link ( `scrollTo` and `href` with `#`) on my Desktop and iPhone 4s. It works fine. Other people are reporting, however, that the links do nothing on their mobile device. The HTML on my page is valid and I have tried everything to get these links to work, but some mobile browsers refuse to recognize the anchor or `.scrollTo()` events.

It might be worthwhile to note the page I'm working on is within an iframe whose parent page is on another domain.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFGT9/

Comment: To clarify: is the link in the iframe? and should the link scroll you to another location within the iframe, or within the parent page? A JSfiddle or link to your page might be handy

Comment: Everything I'm working on is in the same page, and the entire page is within an iframe that is meant to always be viewed on a page which is hosted on another domain. I'm not trying to link to anything outside of my page or outside of the iframe. To clarify: I a not attempting to interact with the parent frame. I'll work on a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WFGT9/

Comment: Updated fiddle to load jQuery, scrollTo and show that it works http://jsfiddle.net/WFGT9/1/

Comment: well, it doesn't work within an iframe, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should look into this. [Click here](http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/?p=134)

```
 $('html,body').animate(
            {
                   scrollTop: 100,
                   scrollLeft: 200
            }, 
           800, 
           function(){
                $('html,body').clearQueue();
           }
 );
```

This wont work on mobiles

Try this

```
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {           
   window.scrollTo(200,100) // first value for left offset, second value for top offset
   }else{
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 100,
            scrollLeft: 200
        }, 800, function(){
            $('html,body').clearQueue();
        });
   }
```

The reason is because the mobile doesn’t know what $(‘html,body’). Try changing it to  animate $(“body”) instead.

Comment: Did u try identifying the device with userAgent.match and using window.scrollTo()?